# Rally query Projects/SubProjects

Tags: project, rally

I'm trying to query for all the projects in the workspace, which I can. But when I try to query for a specific project, I get 0 results.

If I just query for projects, I get a full list.  If I take one of those results and add in a:

```
query: 'Project.Name="Whatever"',
```

I get 0 results.

Full code:

```
     //Works
    var queryConfig = {
    type: 'project',
    key: 'projects',
    fetch: 'Name' 
};


rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showStories);
```

And then

```
    //Doesn't work
    var queryConfig = {
    type: 'project',
    key: 'projects',
    query: 'Project.Name = "Iron Horse"',
    fetch: 'Name' 
};

rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showStories);
```

If I can figure this out, I'm also trying to get a list of all the child projects to that 1 project.  I am having no success in that regard either, but I belive to even do that I'd need my first query to work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this query param will get you what you want:

query: '(Name = "Iron Horse")',

Comment: Okay. That worked. Now I want to get the names of the Children for that project.

Adding 
  
    fetch: Children

Returns an array of Objects.  It seems no matter how I approach those objects, Rally returns an error.  How can I get the names of those Children?

Comment: Each member of the Children array is an object that has a _refObjectName member, that's what you want.